# Using request path with a parameter in an if statement

Tags: node.js

I have some middleware where I need to detect the following path which `/events/ followed by any id string:

```
if (req.path === "/events/:eventId" && req.method === "GET") {
    ...
}
```

But this doesn't work because of the `:eventId` part. How can I make this work?

This should be detected:

```
/events/123456
```

but any other path types like this shouldn't:

```
/events/123456/image
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a regex like

```js
function foo (path) {
  if (/^\/events\/[^\/]+$/.test(path)) {
    // matches any string starting with /events/
    // plus at least one character that is not another / before the end
    console.log('matched');
  } else {
    console.log('did not match');
  }
}


foo('/events/123456');
// 'matched'
foo('/events/123456/image');
// 'did not match'
foo('/events/'); // bonus
// 'did not match'
foo('/events/123456/'); // but note this tricky one
// 'did not match'

// if you also want to accept '/events/123456/' you could change it to
const betterRegex = /^\/events\/[^\/]+\/?$/;
console.log(betterRegex.test('/events/123456/'));
// true
console.log(betterRegex.test('/events/123456/images'));
// false

// plus you can capture the ID by adding a capture group with ()
const id =  /^\/events\/([^\/]+)\/?$/.exec('/events/123456')[1]
console.log(id) // '123456'
```

But if you have a lot of routes I'd recommend using something like express.js because it makes dealing with them much easier.